# How can we move pin/marker in Arcgis?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, maps, arcgis

In one of my application I need to move marker on drag and drop, once user drop the pin I need to get the dropped pin location.
This is very basic feature of map but I am surprised that there is no such option in the library.
In native map there is property called "Draggable", is there any equivalent property in the Arcgis ?

Comment: Are you using ArcMap, ArcGIS JavaScript API, or some other tool?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I am using Arcgis-runtime sdk for ios.
I find the answer and I have posted the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `ARCGIS` community support, I was able to find the answer for this question.
We have to implement the method [mapView:didMoveTapAndHoldAtPoint:mapPoint:features:](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/protocol_a_g_s_map_view_touch_delegate-p.html#a11c0e276396abe877c2eec285c4a87af) on `AGSMapViewTouchDelegate`.
The delegate method gets called every time the user moves his finger while taping and holding the map view. The method also provides the array of features at that location. So in the method you can update the geometry of the features to the new `mapPoint`.

You can use this [sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios/tree/master/OfflineRoutingSample) as a reference. The sample adds a marker if you tap and hold and changes the location of that marker when you move while taping and holding.